# expression evaluation with boolean values

Tags: javascript

In Java or other similar languages I can't do:

```
a < b > c
```

where a,b,c are boolean types.

In Javascript I can do that and also with other data types values:

```
var t = 3;
var z = true;

t > z // will be true
```

Now why the results is true???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True will be converted to 1. And 3 is greater than one...

Answer (score 4):

Because Javascript is willing to do type conversions at the drop of a hat.  Boolean `true` is coerced to numeric `1`.

Note that `1 == true` is `true`, but `1 === true` is `false`.

Comment: +1.  Also, `a < b > c` will be evaluated as `(a < b) > c` and since `a < b` evaluates to a boolean, `> c` is testing if the resulting casted integer (1 or 0) is greater than c.

Comment: Indeed. To me, all these explanations constitute reasons to expunge code like that whenever it's encountered :-)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript first casts the boolean `true` to a number for the comparison. In this case `true` is cast to `1`.

Many objects will not be cast to numbers though. For example, `{}` is `NaN`.